# Why can't I reference original android theme attribute from colors.xml?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

My custom application theme is `CustomTheme`, its parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. I do not define `textColorPrimaryInverse` item in my custom theme. In `colors.xml` I define a color which I want to be equal to `textColorPrimaryInverse` attribute of the the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. So I reference it like this:

```
<color name="enabled_blue_button_text">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</color>
```

This gives me a runtime exception "No resource found that matches the given name". If I reference `?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse` in `styles.xml` instead of `colors.xml` it works fine.

If I define `textColorPrimaryInverse` in my custom theme after all..

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
```

... referencing from `colors.xml` works.

**QUESTION 1. Why can't I reference android theme attribute from colors.xml**

But I don't want to define this attribute in my custom theme. At the very least I'm ready to define it to be equal to the parent attribute.

**QUESTION 2. If there's no way to do without redefining this attribute in the custom theme, can I define sth like this:**

`<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">`**`ref to parent attribute`**`</item>`
?

Comment: As far as I know, `:attr` is used to refer elements in your current theme. `colors` file might be independent of the theme. I am not sure about the answer tho